# OldNetworkTopologyStrategy and NetworkTopologyStrategy

Tags: cassandra

Please explain to me more detail about OldNetworkTopologyStrategy and NetworkTopologyStrategy ? How can it work ? And the flow when data comes to cassandra by that ways/

Thank you for your read.

Answer (score 3):

NetworkTopologyStrategy is described in DataStax's Cassandra documentation [here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/cluster_architecture/replication).

OldNetworkTopologyStrategy is provided for backwards compatibility with old Cassandra installations. You don't need to worry about it if you're deploying a new cluster.